# Not waiting for async tests to complete before executing after event in moch test

Tags: promise, mocha.js, cypress

I'm writing a file pre-processor for Cypress. Cypress uses mocha internally. So I'm generating mocha test from a feature file on the fly. Here, is the sample code.

```
function runTests( features ){

    for(let f_i=0; f_i < features.length; f_i++){
        const feature = features[f_i];
        let scenarioCount = {    count: 0 };

        describe("Feature: " + feature.statement, () => {
            for(let s_i=0; s_i < rule.scenarios.length; s_i++){
                const scenario = rule.scenarios[s_i];
                runScenario(scenario, scenarioCount);
            }

            /*
            afterEach(() => {
                if(scenarioCount.count === feature.stats.total) saveResult(feature); 
            });
            */
            /*
            after(() => {
                saveResult(feature); 
            });
            */
            it("__After", function(){
                cy.then( () => {
                    saveResult(feature)
                });
            })
        } );//describe ends
    }
}

function saveResult(feature){
    cy.writeFile(someFileName, feature);
    cy.writeFile(someFileName2, feature);
}

function runScenario(scenario, count){
    it("test statement", function(){
        return cy.then(() => { //return promise
            //run all the steps in a scenario
        })
    })
}
```

- This code runs in browser. Hence I'm supposed to use `cy.write()` to save any data on the disk. `cy` can be used within the test function `it` or some event ( eg. `after`).

I'm saving the status of each step within the feature object itself and saving it on the disk once all the tests are completed. But, when I use `after` or `afterEach` mocha event for the same, they somehow executes before completion of all the tests.

But if I use `it` in last instead of `after` events then it runs in order and I get desire result. I want to avoid extra `it` to save the feature object.

```
on('task', {
//to print logs to console
mydebug (message) {
    console.log( "DEBUG::" , msg);
    return null;
}
});
```

Comment: That happened to me when I forget to encapsulate them in the  `describe` function that encapsulates the `it` cases. check if it is the case

Comment: No that's not the case here. Please check the code I shared in the question

Comment: try adding return to the function saveResult like `return cy.writeFile(someFileName, feature);` or wrap it in a callback, because I have a feeling Cypress is treating it as a Sycnronous code and running it in the beginning. `cy.log('afterEach').then(()=>{saveResult(feature);})`

Comment: This is a good point. So I tried various combinations with `cy.wrap()`, `cy.log()`, and `cy.then()` in `after` event. This give error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addCommand' of undefined` for `cy.visit()` used in code. And it still runs `cy.writeFile` before all tests are completed. However, if I use `cy.task()` with this combination then all the tests run before `after` event. But the error doesn't go away.

Comment: I know it requires more work, but since I had similar problems in the beginning, I started doing every case in it`s own file and making all the setup and clear up inside the "it" case. That works fine for me for more than a year and is more easy to maintain. And instead of organizing several cases in a file - I organize them in a folder.